# How to get custom slot in v-data-iterator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to get custom slot in v-data-iterator?
For this example I would like to change inside Calories slot the color of the "Calories" text and add "kcal" text to value.

**What i want to get:**
[image: screenshot]

**I tried something like this:**

```
<!-- Custom slot for Calories -->
<template v-slot:item="calories">
  <v-list-item>
    <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
      <!-- Custom value here (green color) -->
      <span style="color: green;">Calories:</span>
    </v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-content class="align-end" :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
      <!-- Custom value here (+ kcal) -->
      {{ item.calories }} kcal
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</template>
```

What should be the correct "v-slot:" value for Calories section? Is there any other way to separate specific sections?

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-data-iterator
        :items="items"
        :items-per-page.sync="itemsPerPage"
        :page.sync="page"
        :search="search"
        :sort-by="sortBy.toLowerCase()"
        :sort-desc="sortDesc"
        hide-default-footer
      >
        <template v-slot:header>
          <v-toolbar
            dark
            color="blue darken-3"
            class="mb-1"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              clearable
              flat
              solo-inverted
              hide-details
              prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
              label="Search"
            ></v-text-field>
            <template v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp">
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-select
                v-model="sortBy"
                flat
                solo-inverted
                hide-details
                :items="keys"
                prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Sort by"
              ></v-select>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn-toggle
                v-model="sortDesc"
                mandatory
              >
                <v-btn
                  large
                  depressed
                  color="blue"
                  :value="false"
                >
                  <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  large
                  depressed
                  color="blue"
                  :value="true"
                >
                  <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-btn-toggle>
            </template>
          </v-toolbar>
        </template>
  
        <template v-slot:default="props">
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              v-for="item in props.items"
              :key="item.name"
              cols="12"
              sm="6"
              md="4"
              lg="3"
            >
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="subheading font-weight-bold">
                  {{ item.name }}
                </v-card-title>
  
                <v-divider></v-divider>
  
                <v-list dense>
                  <v-list-item
                    v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys"
                    :key="index"
                  >
                    <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
                      {{ key }}:
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-content
                      class="align-end"
                      :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }"
                    >
                      {{ item[key.toLowerCase()] }}
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </template>
  
        <template v-slot:footer>
          <v-row
            class="mt-2"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <span class="grey--text">Items per page</span>
            <v-menu offset-y>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-btn
                  dark
                  text
                  color="primary"
                  class="ml-2"
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on"
                >
                  {{ itemsPerPage }}
                  <v-icon>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(number, index) in itemsPerPageArray"
                  :key="index"
                  @click="updateItemsPerPage(number)"
                >
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ number }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
  
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  
            <span
              class="mr-4
              grey--text"
            >
              Page {{ page }} of {{ numberOfPages }}
            </span>
            <v-btn
              fab
              dark
              color="blue darken-3"
              class="mr-1"
              @click="formerPage"
            >
              <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              fab
              dark
              color="blue darken-3"
              class="ml-1"
              @click="nextPage"
            >
              <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-row>
        </template>
      </v-data-iterator>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      itemsPerPageArray: [4, 8, 12],
      search: '',
      filter: {},
      sortDesc: false,
      page: 1,
      itemsPerPage: 4,
      sortBy: 'name',
      keys: [
        'Name',
        'Calories',
        'Fat',
        'Carbs',
        'Protein',
        'Sodium',
        'Calcium',
        'Iron',
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          sodium: 87,
          calcium: '14%',
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: '8%',
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          sodium: 337,
          calcium: '6%',
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 413,
          calcium: '3%',
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          sodium: 327,
          calcium: '7%',
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          sodium: 50,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          sodium: 38,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          sodium: 562,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          sodium: 326,
          calcium: '2%',
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          sodium: 54,
          calcium: '12%',
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    numberOfPages () {
      return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.itemsPerPage)
    },
    filteredKeys () {
      return this.keys.filter(key => key !== 'Name')
    },
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage () {
      if (this.page + 1 <= this.numberOfPages) this.page += 1
    },
    formerPage () {
      if (this.page - 1 >= 1) this.page -= 1
    },
    updateItemsPerPage (number) {
      this.itemsPerPage = number
    },
  },
})
```

**Full demo code:**
https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/GRNrddz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct **v-slot** for doing this.

Your values are in **v-list-item-content**, but not in general **v-data-iterator**. Unfortunately, v-list-item-content has only **default** slot.

But you may solve your problem this way:

```
...
<v-list dense>
  <v-list-item
    v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys"
    :key="index"
  >
    <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
      <span v-if="key === 'Calories'" style="color: green">
      {{ key }}:
      </span>
      <span v-else>
      {{ key }}:
      </span>
    </v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-content
      class="align-end"
      :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }"
    >
      <span v-if="key === 'Calories'">
        {{ item[key.toLowerCase()] + ' kcal' }}
      </span>
      <span v-else>
        {{ item[key.toLowerCase()] }}
      </span>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
...
```